# Streamed Video Fallback to Local mp4 Video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Is there a way, using html or javascript, to backup a linked streamed video with a local video (same video)?

I am working on a project, using Zurb Foundation 6 Sites, that needs an embedded streamed video on a page, for when there is an internet connection, but then defaults to the same video locally when there is no connection, and therefor the user sees no error on the page and one video window.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
      <div id="webvideo" class="responsive-embed flex-video widescreen">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/examplevideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div id="filevideo" class="flex-video widescreen">
        <video controls width="420" height="315" src="../assets/vid/video.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I dont think html5 has anything like this and I am unsure of how to do this with JavaScript. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: there is an `error` event... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Error_handling

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, I looked at the documentation but it doesn't show how to handle iframe. I tried some things using javascript but could get it to work.